# Dealing cards randomly in javascript - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to deal 8 cards randomly in jQuery, but whenever I run my code after the 8 cards are dealt the browser crashes. It says that I have a problem on line 144 in my while loop.
I made this while loop to deal eight unique random cards.

```
var n = 0
var card = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 6}, {id: 7}, {id: 8}];
var arr = [];
var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1);

doOne(0, n);

function doOne(index, rand) {
    var thisCard = card[index];
    var p = $("#hand1_" + thisCard.id);
    var offset = p.offset();
    var zindex = p.css('z-index');
    if (thisCard) {
        $('#card' + rand).css('z-index', zindex);

        $('#card' + rand).animate({
            top: offset.top,
            left: offset.left,
            }, 
            function() {
                arr.push(rand);
                k = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
                // line 144 i have a problem here
                while (exist(arr, k) == true || arr.length == 8) {
                    k = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
                }
                doOne(index + 1, k);
            });
     }
}

function exist(arr, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == obj)
            return true;
    }
}
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I suggest that you just use the index of the element as id, rather than assigning it manually.

Comment: What sort of "problem" does it say you have?  Is there an actual error message?

Comment: when it crashes using mozzila firefox , it says that i have a problem in line 144 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do:

```
var n = 0
var card = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 6}, {id: 7}, {id: 8}];
var arr = [];
var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1);

doOne(0, n);

function doOne(index, rand) {
    var thisCard = card[index];
    var p = $("#hand1_" + thisCard.id);
    var offset = p.offset();
    var zindex = p.css('z-index');
    if (thisCard) {
        $('#card' + rand).css('z-index', zindex);

        $('#card' + rand).animate({
            top: offset.top,
            left: offset.left,
        }, 
        function() {
            arr.push(rand);
            k = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
            // line 144 i have a problem here
            while (exist(arr, k) == true && arr.length < 8) {
                k = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
            }
            doOne(index + 1, k);
        });
     }
}

function exist(arr, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == obj)
            return true;
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `while` loop will keep looping as long as `arr.length==8` evaluates to true. Within the `while` loop you are not changing the number of items of `arr` and therefor it will keep looping forever once the number of items reaches 8.

Edit: It probably still crashes because `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. If you multiply this number by 8 and add 1, this number is basically always between 1 and 8, including. This domain consists of 8 integral numbers, the same as the number of elements in your array when the loop keeps looping forever. Since there are 8 numbers in your array and `k` is a number between 1 and 8 every time, `k` will always be a number that already exists in your array. Therefor it starts looping forever. If you want to deal more than 8 cards, you will have to create a function that can result in a number outside the range 1 to 8.

Comment: even when i remove arr.length==8 , it still crashes

Comment: can you give an ending condition ??

Comment: yes but i need a number between 1 and 8 that's the problem , unique 8 numbers

Comment: @ziz194 Then there are only 8 numbers available for you. How do you want to add a 9th unique number to your array then? Because that is what you are trying to do and your script is not stopping until it succeeded (which will be never, explaining the crash).

Comment: can you give me a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could "lazy shuffle" the stack as you draw cards:

```js
const stack = [/* all cards here */];

function drawRandomCards(amount) {
  const cards = [];

  while (amount > 0) {
    const card = drawRandomCard();

    cards.push(card);
    amount--;
  }

  return cards;
}

function drawRandomCard() {
  if (stack.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("stack is empty");
  }

  const index = randomInt(stack.length);
  const lastIndex = stack.length - 1;

  const card = stack[index];
  const lastCard = stack[lastIndex];

  stack[index] = lastCard;
  stack.pop();

  return card;
}

function randomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
```

There is no need to shuffle the whole stack if you only want to draw /some/ random cards.

Just "shuffle" as you draw.

Hope this proves useful for someone :)